# Yii2: How to allow CORS on non-restfull API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii2, cors

I am working with a pre-built API (not restfull) on Yii2 Framework. It responds with JSON data and accepts requests depending on User type and credential token. Now I have to make an app that is on a different location (domain) which is causing CORS conflict.

My app is jQuery and I'm using `$.ajax` for data sending and receiving.
How can I avoid this CORS conflict and use the API over ajax?

Regards

UPDATE:

As IStranger told me in his answer I added the following code:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
        'cors' => [
            'Origin'                           => "*",
            'Access-Control-Request-Method'    => ['POST', 'GET'],
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
            'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => 3600,
        ],
    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

But I am still getting the error. There is a `beforeAction` in the code can that be a problem?

This is the RAW HEADER

Request:

```
Host: domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost/main/main.html
Content-Length: 296
Origin: http://localhost
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response:

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 101
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 22 Sep 2016 17:23:48 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache/2.4.17 (Win64) PHP/5.6.16
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=ph0b322gbq65m1f3m8fp9fphc0; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.16
```

Comment: Try replace `'Origin' => ["*"],`.
Then check http headers of AJAX request using browser debugger ("Network" tab). Request headers should have `Origin` value, and response headers should have `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Comment: @IStranger OK that worked, but now I get a 500 error but with request type OPTIONS, where as I am POSTing

Comment: @IStranger Ignore my last comment, it still doesn't work.

Comment: What error? Show all http headers of your AJAX request and response.

Comment: Let me add a RAW Header.

Comment: @IStranger Do I need to add something to jQuery ajax code to allow CORS? because I just tried with `HTTPRequester` with Origin localhost in Header it worked, it gave a CORS header.

Comment: I updated anwer. Try disable CSRF validation as I shown.

Comment: It is disabled, its the first thing I did.

Comment: Your controller have any AccessControl or Verb filters (for example, in parent controller class)? 
Try disable  'Access-Control-Request-Method', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'Access-Control-Max-Age'.

Comment: Nope. I dont know how to use behaviours so I avoid using it. As I said, it works with direct HTTP Request but doesn't with the HTML page. Do I need to add something on html page to allow JS to make CORS?

Comment: Usually you no need any special actions on html/js (that sent request). `Origin` header added automatically by browser at crossdomain request. What source and target domains?

Comment: Then try more simple code:

    public function behaviors()
    {
         return [
             'corsFilter' => [
                 'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
             ],
         ];
    }

And check your local web-server. For example, nginx may have some problems. Use 'nginx cross origin header' for search

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add to your API controller:

```
/**
 * List of allowed domains.
 * Note: Restriction works only for AJAX (using CORS, is not secure).
 *
 * @return array List of domains, that can access to this API
 */
public static function allowedDomains()
{
    return [
        // '*',                        // star allows all domains
        'http://test1.example.com',
        'http://test2.example.com',
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return array_merge(parent::behaviors(), [

        // For cross-domain AJAX request
        'corsFilter'  => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
            'cors'  => [
                // restrict access to domains:
                'Origin'                           => static::allowedDomains(),
                'Access-Control-Request-Method'    => ['POST'],
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
                'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => 3600,                 // Cache (seconds)
            ],
        ],

    ]);
}
```

This code will add to response special http-headers. Request http header should haves `Origin` (it will be added by browser automatically at Crossdomain AJAX). Response http headers should have `Access-Control-*` headers.

**NOTE:** If you don't see these http headers in response, probably it means that `\yii\filters\Cors` don't works. Check other behaviors/filters in controller. Try to disable CSRF validation for this controller (it may prevent external access):

```
/**
 * Controller for API methods.
 */
class ApiController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @var bool See details {@link \yii\web\Controller::$enableCsrfValidation}.
     */
    public $enableCsrfValidation = false;

    // ...
}
```

**UPD:** Additionally should be checked your web-server. Probably nginx may require additional configuration, apache can require restarting.

**UPD2:** More complete instruction here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42435695/3793592

Comment: I am editing my question regarding your answer please see.

Comment: I restarted Apache and it worked. I guess apache's cache or something made the problem persist.