# how to show result of jquery in another form element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I have following method:

```
public function actionBaustein($textId) {
    $text = PaTextbaustein::findOne($textId)->data;
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return $text;
}
```

and following elements in formular:

```
<?=
        $form->field($model, 'textbaustein_id')->widget(\kartik\widgets\Select2::classname(), [
            'data' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\backend\models\PaTextbaustein::find()->where(['angelegt_von' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])->orderBy('id')->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'beschreibung'),
            'options' => ['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Textbaustein selektieren'),
                'id' => 'bez',
            ],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowClear' => true
            ],
        ]);
        ?>
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
 <?=
        $form->field($model, 'vorlage', ['addon' => [
                'prepend' => ['content' => 'Vorlage']]])->textarea(['id' => 'cke_Text', 'rows' => 22, 'format' => 'html', 'disabled' => true])
        ?>
```

If I will slect one element of id 'bez' using following code:

```
$script = <<< JS
$('#bez').change(function(){
    var textId=$(this).val();
    alert('Der Inhalt des Records der ID:'+textId+' wird in das Feld übernommen. Kopieren Sie ihn ggf. in das Feld -Vorlage-');
    $.get('baustein',{textId:textId},function(data){
        $('#cke_Text').val(data);      
    });
});
```

JS;
$this->registerJS($script);

....I will get following error:

```
XHRGEThttp://localhost:1025/Yii2_PsychoApp/backend/web/index.php/pa-mail/baustein?textId=1
```

[HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 256ms]

GET
http://localhost:1025/Yii2_PsychoApp/backend/web/index.php/pa-mail/baustein?textId=1
Status
403
Forbidden
VersionHTTP/1.1
Übertragen897 B (62 B Größe)
Referrer Policystrict-origin-when-cross-origin

**How to fix this error?**

Comment: Looks like  cross-origin issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643344/yii2-how-to-allow-cors-on-non-restfull-api

Comment: check for your actionBaustein permssion in your PaMailController

Answer (score 0):

Thx a lot toward ScaisEdge. In actual fact, I ddidn't have any permission io order to
carry out actionBaustein. Now, following error will be thrown out:

```
Server error 500: Missing parameter textID
```

Why? I give this parameter in Controller

Got solution at my own:
After using var_dump(), I got it:

```
    public function actionBaustein($textId) {    
    $text = PaTextbaustein::findOne($textId)->content;
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return $text;
}
```